# How to fix depreciation issues after upgrades

Tags: add-on, ee2-upgrades, developer-log

I'm still new to EE and am trying to upgrade a site from 2.6.1 to 2.8.1, but getting various errors, which I believe are all related to certain add-ons.  Here's a couple examples:

Champaign2: Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Fieldtype::EE_Fieldtype() in /system/expressionengine/third_party/champagne/ft.champagne.php

Structure:  Deprecated function add_to_head() called in system/expressionengine/third_party/structure/mcp.structure.php on line 213

Am I right in thinking it's down to the developers to fix these issues as EE depreciates various functions - so I need to get in touch with their support?  Or is it normal for devs to struggle through one issue at a time trying to update the third-party module's code to solve themselves?

Also, are the notices in the developer logs just notices of *future* depreciations?  Or do these logs indicate an actual broken function within the current version?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Usually you just get in touch with support issues. Just to make sure, did you update your version of Champagne as well?

Comment: I did download the latest version from the developer, but the installed version was (supposedly) the same version, so I will try that.

Any idea about the developer logs?  Do those actually indicate errors happening or are they more just warnings that something might break in future?

Comment: Update: I did try updating the module and same issue occurs.  In this case it's not actually being used so I can just remove it, but just trying to get a handle on the overall process.

Comment: If it's throwing a deprecation error, it's on the docket to be removed at some point. The fatal error means that the developer should fix the issue with an updated version. Some add-on developers are faster at doing this than others, but 2.8.1 was released in March of 2014, so there's been a decent amount of time for a commercial developer to get it updated.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming - that is how I assumed, but good to know for sure.  I guess the lesson is only use add-ons that appear to be very well supported.

Comment: Yes, that's a very valuable assumption. Those particular ones are built by great shops though and should both have updates available that fix those errors.

Comment: There is a similar problem with a plugin of the same author: Field Editor. This pllugin before EE2.7 was working fine, and now it's not working even the new release. No exist support, no exist email box to contact the author.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading EE is isn't always the smoothest, but yes you need to ensure all your add-ons have been upgraded by their devs to support the latest version and you should update all your add-ons before updating EE.

Whether new or not to EE, the ***Lamplighter*** add-on is a must have, providing an at-a-glance view of what add-ons are current or need updating:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/lamplighter

Finally, DevDemon's ***Updater*** add-on is great for speeding up the update process with EE to just a few clicks:
http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/updater

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Structure you should just be able to update to the recent version which I believe works fine with 2.8.1.

I'm not so sure about Champagne but it's likely the most recent version will work at least enough to allow you to remove it. Check their support as even if there isn't a working release version there is highly likely to be a quick patch you cam make to the current version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the Structure error is just in the developer logs, so I guess they have time to fix it before it actually breaks anything (I am on the latest version).

With Champagne, it's also the latest version and in this case I can just remove it because the site isn't actually using it, but it makes me nervous to see how reliant upgrades actually are on third parties.  I guess it comes with the territory, but thanks for your input.